# Python - UnicodeDecodeError from byte address?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, byte, decode

I'm attempting to decode byte data I got from an address of a process.  I know using 3rd party software what the value of the byte address is. I retrieved the byte data into a buffer (of type `c_char_p` from `ctypes`).

Then using `buffer.value.decode()` I get `(#` back when I expect to get the value 9000. I changed the value (using the third party software) to 2000. Once I did that I got the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

It seems to me that either UTF-8 is the wrong encoding or I'm doing something else wrong. I tried decoding it as Latin-1 but this was unsuccessful as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, can you post the value of the byte address?

Comment: Try decoding as ctypes.c_int or ctypes.c_long?

Comment: @ChristianTernus: The value I'm seeing at the address is `(#` when it's 9000 (in decimal format according to the third party software) and `\xd0\x07' when it's suppose to be 2000.

Comment: @MarkkuK.: I'll give that a try quick...

Comment: @MarkkuK.: Um... taking a quick look around I'm not sure how to decode it as ctypes.c_int or ctypes.c_long. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'\xd0\x07' is the little endian representation of 2000.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ptr = ctypes.c_char_p(b'\xd0\x07')
>>> val = ctypes.c_int()
>>> ctypes.memmove(ctypes.byref(val),ptr,ctypes.sizeof(val))
>>> val.value
2000
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm still doing something else wrong in my main code, but that did get back the correct value, so I should be able to fix it from there. (Oh, but just as a note, you need to put a `b` before the string in the `c_char_p()`)

Comment: Ah, I am still thinking in python 2.7 -- it makes no difference there. I will update the answer though.

Comment: Ah ok, yes I am using 3.3. Also, I figured out my other problem (just had the memmove before the ReadProcessMemory), so everything works great now. Thanks again!